# Return Information of the Stock with the Biggest Percent Change

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter

I was wondering if anyone could help me develop the method needed in order to print out only the information of a stock with the biggest percent change between it's previous closing price and current closing price. Here is a bit of the code that may help with understanding what I'm referring to.

```
public class driveStockList {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Stock stock = new Stock();

    Stock[] Stocks = new Stock[6];

    Stocks[0] = new Stock("ORCL", "Oracle Corporation");
    Stocks[0].setPreviousClosingPrice(34.50);
    Stocks[0].setCurrentPrice(34.35);
    Stocks[0].getChangePercent();

    Stocks[1] = new Stock("MSFT", "Microsoft Corporation");
    Stocks[1].setPreviousClosingPrice(90.13);
    Stocks[1].setCurrentPrice(90.19);
    Stocks[1].getChangePercent();

    Stocks[2] = new Stock("GOOGL", "Alphabet Inc.   ");
    Stocks[2].setPreviousClosingPrice(1139.10);
    Stocks[2].setCurrentPrice(1139.0);
    Stocks[2].getChangePercent();

    Stocks[3] = new Stock("AAPL", "Apple Inc.      ");
    Stocks[3].setPreviousClosingPrice(179.10);
    Stocks[3].setCurrentPrice(179.45);
    Stocks[3].getChangePercent();

    Stocks[4] = new Stock("NFLX", "Netflix, Inc.    ");
    Stocks[4].setPreviousClosingPrice(217.50);
    Stocks[4].setCurrentPrice(217.69);
    Stocks[4].getChangePercent();

    Stocks[5] = new Stock("INTC", "Intel Corporation");
    Stocks[5].setPreviousClosingPrice(44.39);
    Stocks[5].setCurrentPrice(44.59);
    Stocks[5].getChangePercent();

    outputStockItems (Stocks);
    outputStockBiggestChange(Stocks);
}

private static void outputStockItems(Stock[] Stocks) {
    System.out.printf("Symbol\t \tName         PreviousClosingPrice\tCurrent Price");
    System.out.printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for ( int i = 0; i < Stocks.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.printf("\n" + Stocks[i].getSymbol());
        System.out.printf("\t" + Stocks[i].getName());
        System.out.printf("\t     " + Stocks[i].getPreviousClosingPrice());
        System.out.printf("       \t" + Stocks[i].getCurrentPrice());
    }

}

public static void outputStockBiggestChange(Stock[] p) {
for ( int i = 5; i < Stocks.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.printf("\n" + Stocks[i].getSymbol());
        System.out.printf("\t" + Stocks[i].getName());
        System.out.printf("\t     " + Stocks[i].getPreviousClosingPrice());
        System.out.printf("       \t" + Stocks[i].getCurrentPrice());
}
```

I have the method set out, but I'm not sure how to go about singling out a singular maximum element/value for the percent change. The body provided for outputStockBiggestChange() is what I believe singles out the stock with the highest change, but I'm sure the code is meant to go through all the values instead of manually directing it to this element.

Comment: Clearly you would calculate the percentages and then compare to see which was the highest percentage change, wouldn't you? If you were doing it with pencil, paper and a calculator, how would you do it?

Comment: @KenWhite I have the formula for finding the percent changes in a separate class and got the answers to print onscreen correctly. My problem is that I'm struggling to just single out the one array element to display all it's information

Comment: What are you struggling with? You keep track of the index along with the percentage.(an array with the same number of elements as `Stocks` would make that very simple). When you determine which has the greatest change, you retrieve the entry from `Stocks` that is at the same index.

Comment: Okay, so then do I need to make another array that's just focused on the percent changes or am I misunderstanding? Because I did try to write the method body for outputStockBiggestChange before posting the question. All I did was change for ( int i = 0; i < Stocks.length; i++ ) and make i = 5 since I believe that is the stock with the highest change and then copy-paste the print statements.

Comment: @CarmenTroye as you said **I have the formula for finding the percent changes in a separate class and got the answers to print onscreen correctly.**
Please update your question with that code. It will help others to guide you.

Comment: You can do it with a loop if you prefer. However, you need to do your own homework. If you're totally stuck, ask your instructor for help. I've offered suggestions, to which you continue to ask more questions about instead o frying to implement them. If we do your assignment for you, you won't learn anything. Good lluck.

Comment: I'm trying to work with a loop at the moment, specifically with for and if loops. I'm just not sure if it's completely correct since I've gotten the program to work, but only by specifying the specific element for the method to look at instead of allowing it to go through. I've actually tried the solution provided below, but the variables don't match up when using Stocks as the index. Anyway, thanks for the advice. I'll keep attempting to implement the loops in a different fashion and hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
float maxDiff = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < Stocks.length; i++ ) {
    float diff = Stocks[i].getPreviousClosingPrice() - Stocks[i].getCurrentPrice();
    diff = Math.abs(diff);
    if(diff > maxDiff) { 
        maxDiff = diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much defeats the purpose of the entire homework assignment if you do it for them.